# Android Media Player setVolume Issues

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Until now, I was setting my `MediaPlayer` volume by setting the stream volume. I don't want to do that anymore because it messes with user settings. I now take the value from a `SeekBar` (0 to 100) and do `valueFromSeekBar / 100` to get a `float` between 0 and 1 to use in `MediaPlayer.setVolume(float, float)`.

The problem is that the volume level doesn't seem to change. Here is how I set up the `MediaPlayer`:

```
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
player.setLooping(true);
player.prepare();

float alarmVolume = AudioUtils.getMediaPlayerScaledVolume(100, alarm.volume);
if(NetworkUtils.isInCall(context)) {
    alarmVolume = IN_CALL_VOLUME;
}
mediaPlayer.setVolume(alarmVolume, alarmVolume); //I've even tried hardcoding 0.1f
```

No matter what I do, it seems like the value I put in `MediaPlayer.setVolume` gets ignored, and the volume of the stream (in this case the alarm stream) gets used instead. It's most noticeable when the stream volume is set to max, and I play two audio files, one with `MediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f)` and the other with `MediaPlayer.setVolume(0.01f, 0.01f)`. They are almost indistinguishable from one another. I need a way for my users to be able to position the `SeekBar` at 1 and get a barely audible sound, or at 100 and have the max sound. Is this possible or am I gonna have to go back to messing with streams?

Answer (score 0):

Set volume:

it will set maximum value(100) to Alarm Stream.

```
amanager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM), AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Comment: I don't want to mess with the user's audio settings. That can cause issues if another app gains audio focus and the user didn't expect the  volume to be so loud. There can also be issues with restoring the volume after I'm done with it. In any case, I have been testing using it today together with `MediaPlayer.setVolume` and that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be you have two objects "player" and "mediaPlayer"? Here I just used that API, and it works as was to be expected.